# Change the color of a Title of the same class

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I can't seem to find a solution for this. I have a custom css for the titles on my website

```
.qodef-e-title {
    color: black;
}
```

Now I have an "Awards list" element on my page that also uses Titles in the list. I want those titles to be white. I have already added a custom class to the Awards List element via Elementor. But I can not seem to find out how to change the title.  The custom class that I added is "awards".

I hope someone can help me out with this.
This is the url: https://cfxdigital.nl/Schilderwerken/?page_id=1858&lang=en

Its about the text below "
Some things we are proud of."

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please post here your relevant html and css maybe into a working snippet.[something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change the color of the line, years and link icon into white, right?

Then you need to change it as followed:

```css
.qodef-awards-list article.qodef-grid-item {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.qodef-awards-list article.qodef-grid-item .qodef-e-inner {
    color: white;
}

.qodef-button.qodef-layout--textual {
    color: white;
}
```